# Как изображение подвинуть в центр дива?

Tags: css

Как изображение подвинуть в центр дива?

Comment: Приведите html код

Comment: как быстро меняются вопросы. :)

Comment: @Zow, попробуйте читать книги об языках, на которых вы программируете, методом тыка, двигаться будете долго.

htmlbook.ru - полезно для изучения HTML и CSS
php.su - PHP и MySQL

Читайте, учите! Вопросы на уровне первоклассника

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `div{text-align:center}`
2. `img{display:block;margin:0 auto}`
3. `div{background:url(img) center 0 no-repeat}`

Answer (score 0):

```
text-align: center
```

Ну если просто подвинуть в центр div а не позиционировать её по горизонтали и вертикали.

Comment: не получается

Comment: напиши код HTML поглядеть.